# Very fast .NET 4 embedded DB

Tags: .net, database

I'm looking for some fast embedded DB for .net 4 (preferably in-memory).

My usual operations are very simple: given one big table with about 50 cols and 30k rows (can be up to 1m), make queries like SELECT AVG(col1) FROM table WHERE col2 IN (?) AND col3 IN (?) AND col4 < ?, SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE [same], etc. Columns are strings or floats.

I've started with simple .net DataTables + LINQ which are quite fast but obviously size-limited (it crashes long before there is no ram left). Also there are no indexes which I thought should increase performance.

Then I've tried SQLite (devart adapter) with SQL queries, which is like 10 times slower than in-memory datatables. I've made indexes on all columns in this table but this didn't help. I thought SQLite is considered one of the fastest embedded DBs so it's quite disappointing.

Is there fast and scalable alternative? E.g. something like DataTable with indexes that could use a lot of memory (e.g. I don't mind that it will eat several gigs of ram).

Comment: In 64 bit application the RAM should last much longer, since the address space is much larger. So perhaps switch to 64 bit.

Comment: "I've made indexes on all columns in this table but this didn't help." Why did you think this would help? Index only the columns that need indexing.

Comment: @Eugene Shaine Mednikov, have you tried Devart provider with in-memory database or working with file? The second approach will be slower because of working with hard disk drive.

Comment: @Stephen, I need to select on all columns, so I've made indexes accordingly

Comment: @Devart, I'm pretty sure I was working with file-based db. Is it possible to load DB from file to memory and then query in-memory only?

Comment: @Eugene, maybe some ORM like Entity Framework or LinqConnect (LINQ to SQLite implementation) - you can materialize the entire table and then use LINQ to Objects queries you need. http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/

Answer (score 2):

SQLite supports in memory databases, see: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

When you have used this, are you sure that you are using it in memory, not from disk?

Comment: this provider still doesn't work with .net 4, so I've used Devart's

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [STSdb4](http://stsdb.com/). It's an embedded .NET 4.0 database that is based on WaterfallTree - an innovative data indexing structure. STSdb4 is away faster than B-tree based databases. It offers blazing speeds in realtime indexing of records with sequential and random keys. There is a [database comparison tool](http://stsdb.com/forum/stsdb-4-x/advanced-topics/344-stsdb4-speeddemo.html) that can help you with your decision.

The above benchmark tool contains the following databases:

- Access 2013
- BrightstarDB
- CassandraDB
- Db4objects
- Derby
- Firebird
- H2
- HamsterDB
- levelDB
- MongoDB
- MS SQL
- MySQL
- Oracle Berkeley
- Perst
- Postgre
- RaptorDB
- RavenDB
- ScimoreDB
- Siaqodb
- SQLite
- STSdb
- VelocityDB
- Volante

Comment: STSDB uses a generalized B-Tree, so it's also B-Tree based.

Comment: Generalized B-tree does not mean B-tree based. WaterfallTree (used in STSdb) is based on the concept of Buffer Trees and is different in its internal structure as well as performance.

Comment: Note for anyone interested in STS.  The licenses are either GPL2 or paid.  If you are wanting this for a software application, the open-source license might not work for you if your project will be a closed-source project.

Answer (score 1):

How about an array?

Define a type with your 50 columns, load the data into an array, and do LINQ queries on it.

You don't have indexes in LINQ to Objects, but it's still pretty fast.

Comment: This is basically what I do with DataTables. There are 2 problems: no indexes and boxing/unboxing when doing query. E.g. when I write
`from r in table where (double)r["Col"] < 2.0` I see that it creates doubles all the time which is insane (.

Comment: A strongly-typed array avoids the boxing problem. You can create in-memory indexes by just calling `ToLookup` (if you only need to search using equality) or by using `OrderBy`, `GroupBy`, and/or `ToArray` with `Array.BinarySearch` (if you need to search using inequality).